# ClickOnce WPF App not Running on other Machines

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2017, clickonce, publishing

I've published a C# WPF app using ClickOnce. The app installs and runs without issue on the machine that I used to create the app. It also installs on other machines without any errors or log messages.

When I run the app by double-clicking the desktop shortcut or using the Start menu shortcut, ClickOnce will run (which I can see in Task Manager) and it will check for updates; but then nothing happens. The app window doesn't appear, the app doesn't show as running in Task Manager, and there are no error messages or logs.

I've tried it on 2 other computers with the same results on each. I'm installing the app from the deployed folder, accessed over our network. I've confirmed that the other computers have .NET 4.6.1 (the version targeted by the app) and I've put the 4.6.1 offline installer in the prerequisites folder, just for good measure. I've tried re-publishing, uninstalling, and reinstalling several times; I get the same results each time.

I've read through Microsoft's documentation and looked at multiple tutorials and can't find anything that I've missed. I'm hoping someone here can help or at least point me toward the best way to try and troubleshoot this.

**- EDIT -**

In response to the comment below by Lews Therin, I'm including the Event Viewer logs here.  There are 2 error messages and an information log at the time stamp that I attempted to run the app again, so something is definitely going wrong with it.

I'll admit that I'm not very familiar with these types of logs; any assistance or direction on figuring out how to parse this information would be much appreciated.

**Log #1**
Windows Error Reporting:
- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Windows Error Reporting 
  - EventID 1001 
   [ Qualifiers]  0 
   Level 4 
   Task 0 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2018-07-09T20:32:53.678375700Z 
   EventRecordID 9118 
   Channel Application 
   Computer NEWRE 
   Security

- EventData

  1806639054918107500 
  5 
  CLR20r3 
  Not available 
  0 
  Order Management App v1.3.exe 
  1.0.0.0 
  5b43975e 
  mscorlib 
  4.7.3110.0 
  5ae8c225 
  1189 
  6a 
  System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse

  \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER62E8.tmp.mdmp \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER6971.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER69EF.tmp.xml \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER69FD.tmp.csv \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER6A8A.tmp.txt 
  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Order Management_062907d9d894cee17b7efa78a8149ec994ec4ef_257ae95b_2bbc7075

  0 
  ba366769-6b13-439b-84f3-ee1229edf3d2 
  2147487744 
  3c8cd2034a7915dc691278a601bdc16c 
  0

**Log #2**
Application Error:
- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Application Error 
  - EventID 1000 
   [ Qualifiers]  0 
   Level 2 
   Task 100 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2018-07-09T20:32:49.767127600Z 
   EventRecordID 9117 
   Channel Application 
   Computer NEWRE 
   Security

- EventData

  Order Management App v1.3.exe 
  1.0.0.0 
  5b43975e 
  KERNELBASE.dll 
  10.0.17134.112 
  c863c6f9 
  e0434352 
  0010db52 
  1820 
  01d417c3ff8df91d 
  C:\Users\office\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\45VVVJR0.JPP\WH8JZO50.YZT\orde..tion_246267fe9a4e6831_0001.0000_6fabe4376c3b347d\Order Management App v1.3.exe 
  C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll 
  ba366769-6b13-439b-84f3-ee1229edf3d2

**Log #3**
.NET Runtime:
- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  .NET Runtime 
  - EventID 1026 
   [ Qualifiers]  0 
   Level 2 
   Task 0 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2018-07-09T20:32:49.265695700Z 
   EventRecordID 9116 
   Channel Application 
   Computer NEWRE 
   Security

- EventData

  Application: Order Management App v1.3.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ByRef, Boolean ByRef) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, Boolean) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type) at Order_Management_App_v1._3.MainWindow..ctor() Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri) at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri) at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext) at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean) at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup() at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object) at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame) at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object) at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window) at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window) at Order_Management_App_v1._1.App.Main()

Comment: Did you check Event Viewer?

Comment: do you have any hard coded paths in your app that may reference your dev machine?

Comment: You certainly missing something on the client computers. Like Sorceri said check if there are any paths that does't exist, or if you have reference to DLL's, those should be copied to client computer as well.  If nothing helps, remove your startup uri and start your mainwindow from app.cs and do it in a try/catch where you can write the exception to the disk. You don't really have to make an installation to test it first. Just build your project and copy the debug or release folder a USB to test it on client computer

Comment: Unhandled error has raised in Activator.CreateInstance() Main window constructor: "Order_Management_App_v1._3.MainWindow..ctor() Exception Info:"  check out code there

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I checked through my code and can't find any hard-coded paths.  I have a reference to the desktop, but it is coded as `public static string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);`, so I don't think that should be an issue.  I tried doing what you suggested by removing the startup uri; I've never had to do this before, so I used the first 2 sets of example code in the answer to this question, but it didn't behave any differently: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142734/how-to-run-mainwindow-loaded-from-app-xaml-cs).  Any thoughts?

Comment: These logs you are referring to, are they from your application or from Windows event viewer ? I also mentioned DLL's in your project. Do you refer to any external DLL ? Can you post a picture of your SOLUTION>PROJECT>References ?

Comment: The logs above are from Event Viewer.  [Here is a screenshot of my project's references](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16cNiaVuUg5VUTcJKEDIhainPZeymmuPN).  To the best of my knowledge, I'm not referencing any external DLL's, but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: Well you are wrong... You are using google api's and some other references... all of those has to exist on the Clients computer, or you have to copy them there with your project. Right click on each reference and see if they are copied locally.

Comment: BTW Windows event viewer will not show you logs from your app unless you manually send your logs to it.

Comment: i went though the references in my project. The QuickBooks SDK reference QBFC13 wasn't locally copied; it comes installed with QuickBooks, but the other machines had out-of-date versions.  After updating that on the other machines, the app will load the main window on them, but with none of it's controls, and then crash. I tried using the code on [the MSDN site here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-open-and-append-to-a-log-file) to collect log information, but the log file isn't updating.

Comment: Here is the try/catch I've got in my MainWindow()

`try
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FileNameTxtBx.DataContext = uiStatus;
    uiStatus.FileName = filePath;
    CompletedFolderTxtBx.DataContext = uiStatus;
    uiStatus.CompFolderName = savePath;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(desktop + "\\Logs\\log.txt")) { DirAppend.Log(e.Message, w); }
    using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText(desktop + "\\Logs\\log.txt")) { DirAppend.DumpLog(r); }
}`

Comment: Looks too complicated: Try with `using (var sw = new StreamWriter("log.txt", true)) sw.WriteLine(e.ToString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and a lot of help from folks in the comments, I've figured out what the issue was.  The original problem happened because Interop.QBFC13 (the reference for the QuickBooks SDK library) can't be copied locally through Visual Studio.  So, unless you manual add it to the references for your project (see the first answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511080/how-to-add-qbfc13-0-msm-to-clickonce)), the machine that your app will be run on will need to have the same version of the SDK installed on it.  The download for QBFC13 (currently the most recent version) can be found [here](https://developer.intuit.com/Downloads/Restricted?filename=qbsdk130.exe).

The later issues happened because I needed to undo an earlier fix (removing the StartupUri) that I had attempted and messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I did face this problem in my company also. In my company before I install any application on user computer they (IT Support) have to approve the application to install on their computer then only it will allow to run/open that application. You can also check the same with your IT Support is there any policy to install new application.